# How to invert a PyTorch Embedding?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have an multi-task encoder/decoder model in PyTorch with a (trainable) `torch.nn.Embedding` embedding layer at the input.

In one particular task, I'd like to pre-train the model self-supervised (to re-construct masked input data) and use it for inference (to fill in gaps in data).

I guess for training time I can just measure loss as the distance between the input embedding and the output embedding... But for inference, how do I invert an `Embedding` to reconstruct the proper category/token the output corresponds to? I can't see e.g. a "nearest" function on the Embedding class...

Comment: To `invert an Embedding to reconstruct the proper category/token the output corresponds to`, you'd usually add a classifier over the output embedding (e.g. with a softmax) to find the predicted token or class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it quite easily:

```
import torch

embeddings = torch.nn.Embedding(1000, 100)
my_sample = torch.randn(1, 100)
distance = torch.norm(embeddings.weight.data - my_sample, dim=1)
nearest = torch.argmin(distance)
```

Assuming you have `1000` tokens with `100` dimensionality this would return nearest embedding based on euclidean distance. You could also use other metrics in similar manner.

Comment: Shouldn't `embeddings(nearest)` be equals (or similar) to `my_sample`? Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, after training. This snippet is focused on ibtaining embeddings closest to current sample and assumes embeddings are somehow close.